# Set ET.SubElement.text to dict.value if dict.key equals other XML node within same parent

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

So, I'm creating a new subelement with ElementTree where the text of the new node should be a dict value IF dict key of the corresponding value equals the text of another XML node within the same parent Node.

## XML example:

```
<ns0:scaleType xmlns:ns0="http://someURL.com/">
  <scales>
    <scale>
        <names>
            <name id="0">abc</name>
            <name id="1" />
        </names>
        <alternativeExportValues>
        </alternativeExportValues>
    </scale>
    <scale>
        <names>
            <name id="0">def</name>
            <name id="1" />
        </names>
        <alternativeExportValues>
        </alternativeExportValues>
    </scale>
 </scales>
</ns0:scaleType>
```

## CSV example:

```
name;value
abc;10012
def;20025
```

## Python code now:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import csv

csvData = []

with open('myCSV.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        csvData.append({'name': row[0], 'value': row[1]})

tree = ET.parse('myXml.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def my_Function():
    for p in csvData:
        for name in root.findall(".//name[@id='0']"):
            text = name.text
            if p['name'] == text:
                value = p['value']
                return value
my_Function()


for elem in root.iter('alternativeExportValues'):
    newNode = ET.SubElement(elem, 'alternativeExportValue')
    newNode.text = 

tree.write("myNewXML.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```

## Expected outcome:

```
<ns0:scaleType xmlns:ns0="http://someURL.com/">
  <scales>
    <scale>
        <names>
            <name id="0">abc</name>
            <name id="1" />
        </names>
        <alternativeExportValues>
           <alternativeExportValue>10012</alternativeExportValue>
        </alternativeExportValues>
    </scale>
    <scale>
        <names>
            <name id="0">def</name>
            <name id="1" />
        </names>
        <alternativeExportValues>
           <alternativeExportValue>20025</alternativeExportValue>
        </alternativeExportValues>
    </scale>
 </scales>
</ns0:scaleType>
```

I tried to put the for loop that creates the `alternativeExportValue` node in `my_Function`, but ended up getting the same value in `newNode.text` or getting stuck in an endless loop.

As you can see in the expected outcome, I want the dict.value as text for the newly created Node if it matches the 
`<name id="0">` innerText within the same parent `<scale>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what `my_Function` is supposed to be doing, but consider the following logic:

- Read/process the CSV data. (You're already doing this, but consider [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead. This will map the values to a dict using the keys from the first row.)
- Process each `scale` element.
- Create a new `alternativeExportValue` element with the "value" value.
- Check to see if the `name` element with the `id` attribute value "0" matches the current "name" entry.
- If it does, append the new `alternativeExportValue` element.

Example...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

with open('myCSV.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    tree = ET.parse('myXml.xml')

    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";"):
        name = row.get("name")
        new_aev_elem = ET.Element("alternativeExportValue")
        new_aev_elem.text = row.get("value")
        for scale in tree.findall(".//scale"):
            name0 = scale.find("names/name[@id='0']")
            if name0.text == name:
                aevs_elem = scale.find("alternativeExportValues")
                aevs_elem.append(new_aev_elem)
                break

    tree.write("myNewXML.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```

This works but isn't very efficient because you have to process every `scale` element that precedes the actual `scale` element you want modify.

Even worse, if you remove the `break` it would process every `scale` element in the XML (for every row of the CSV!).

If you can switch to [lxml](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html), you can use a slightly more complex XPath* that will only process the `scale` element that needs to be modified...

```
from lxml import etree
import csv

with open('myCSV.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    tree = etree.parse('myXml.xml')

    uc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    lc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";"):
        name = row.get("name").lower()
        new_aev_elem = etree.Element("alternativeExportValue")
        new_aev_elem.text = row.get("value")
        aevs_elem = tree.xpath(f".//scale[translate(names/name[@id='0'],'{uc}','{lc}')='{name}']/alternativeExportValues")[0]
        aevs_elem.append(new_aev_elem)

    tree.write("myNewXML.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```

*The [XPath support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) in ElementTree is limited.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Haley. My idea with the `my_Function` was to find the value of the matching key in `.//name[@id="0"]`.

I tried switching to lxml but `aevs_elem = tree.xpath(f".//scale[names/name[@id='0']='{name}']/alternativeExportValues")[0]`
returns `IndexError: list index out of range`.
So this means the xPath doesn't exist.

Comment: @Alecbalec - Did you also switch to DictReader? If not, you're probably processing the first line of the CSV and the XPath is failing because of `name[@id='0']='name'`. If you don't want to switch to DictReader, you can either skip the first line of the CSV or use a try/except. If you _did_ switch to DictReader, there must be something different in either your CSV or XML because I tested with what you have in your question and don't get any errors.

Comment: First all, thank you very much!
The first problem was the encoding when reading the csv file.
In the for loop i ran `print(row)` to see the output and it returned `'\ufeffname':` instead of `name:`. Changed the encoding to `"utf-8-sig"` and things looked better.

I Uncommented the code and added a `print(get.('value')` to see at which line in the .csv file the code actually breaks. After a quick look it was obvious that the `xPath` is case-sensitive and that's why it returned `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Alecbalec - Ahh yes XPath is definitely case sensitive. Forcing a value to uppercase or lowercase is kind of a pain in XPath 1.0 (which is what lxml supports), but I'll update my lxml answer so it's case insensitive.

Comment: Yeah, luckily it was only a few lines where one character was lowercase in the orginial XML file and upper in the csv.
Again, thank you.